# How to avoid (or lessen the risk of) corruption of the suo file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, suo

I know that this question is a little "questionable" because it doesn't have a concrete and precise answer, but before you downvote I ask you to see for **the value of the question itself**. Lots of SO users had suffered this problem, and someone may found a solution or ways to minimize the problems it cause.

When the .suo file gets corrupts, it becomes a headache:

- Intellisense stops working
- When reopening the proyect/solution, it does not remember open files
- Some strange old-settings that you though were disabled appear again (in my case, an old debug configuration that I deleted a week ago resurfaced)

The only solution I found is to close VS, delete the .suo file and let VS create it again, but yet it makes you abruptly stop working on whatever you were doing, close and reopen everything, and configure the view as you had it before you stopped...

Once it becomes corrupt is clear that you need to delete it, lots of posts show it, but I'm asking if someone found what could be done before it happens.

**What did you do to avoid the .suo file become corrupt, or lessen the probability of it happenning?**

**Note:** I'm using VS'12, but I found that users of VS'10 also had this problem, that's the reason of the double tag

Comment: Can't exactly avoid bugs in visual studio, and the problems you list are probably multiple bugs scattered everywhere. If you have the cash contact microsoft devs.